# template class has no acceptable convertion

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

The following code works fine:

```
struct A {
    int d;
    A(int _d) : d(_d) {}
};
A operator+(const A& x, const A& y) {
    return x.d + y.d;
}
int main() {
    A x = 6;
    cout << (x + 4).d << endl;
    cout << (4 + x).d << endl;
}
```

However, if I make `A` a template class, then it doesn't compile:

```
template<int p>
struct A {
    int d;
    A(int _d) : d(_d) {}
};
template<int p>
A<p> operator+(const A<p>& x, const A<p>& y) {
    return x.d + y.d;
}
int main() {
    A<0> x = 6;                // OK
    cout << (x + 4).d << endl; // error: no operator found or there is no acceptable convertion
    cout << (4 + x).d << endl; // error: no operator found or there is no acceptable convertion
}
```

It works when I do explicit convertion `A<0>(4)` or `(A<0>)4`, but it's annoying.

I would like to know what causes this difference between "normal" and "template" classes, and how can I get implicit convertion working.

I'm using MSVC compiler, if that matters.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, I added the tag according to your suggestion.

Comment: Does it work if you define the operator as a friend inside the class definition (instead of standalone)?

Comment: I think it's because the compiler can't deduce what the template argument for conversion of the `int` constants to an `A<T>` should be. Same as if you try: `A x = 6;`, giving *error : no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'A'*

Comment: Template argument deduction doesn't consider implicit conversions.

Comment: @bobah Yes, it mysteriously works! So why is this happending? It all looks very subtle to me.

Comment: @WhatsUp - see the AnoopRana answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that **template argument deduction** doesn't consider **implicit conversions** like the one **converting constructor** that you've provided.

From [template argument deduction's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. The comment of @bobah seems to solve the practical problem for me.

Comment: Making half of the words in a sentence bold doesn't help clarify anything.

Comment: @super It is to me. I like to do that.